# Improved isinstance for IPython

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Problem**: IPython's `autoreload` and `superreload` may reload modules such that `obj=Obj()` -> edit file & save -> `isinstance(obj, Obj) == False`. Sometimes even `imp.reload` of all involved modules doesn't absolve it.

**Goal**: a method with a 'fallback' on looser criterion that are as close to `isinstance` as possible.

**Attempt**:

```py
def isinstance_ipython(obj, ref_class):
    def _class_name(obj):
        name = getattr(obj, '__qualname__', getattr(obj, '__name__', ''))
        return (getattr(obj, '__module__', '') + '.' + name).lstrip('.')
    return (isinstance(obj, ref_class) or 
            _class_name(type(obj)) == _class_name(ref_class))
```

`obj` is always instance of a class, and `ref_class` is always a Python 3.x, non-builtin class. `__qualname__` and `__module__` are included to prefer longest possible name, but fallback upon shorter names via empty strings.

---

Any improvements to reliability of this method (i.e. reduced false positives/negatives)? Not interested in speed or readability, but they're welcome as bonus.